# Windows 7 x64 BSOD while gaming with gtx570, motherbord?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, troubleshooting, bsod

I get a BSOD almost whenever I've gamed for a little while and try to save the game or do something else that explicitly writes to disk. I don't know if it's actually the disk writing part or anything else that causes the problem but I've run many different error checking tools and haven't found an issue anywhere. I'm beginning to think it could have to do with the motherboard or at least the marvel chipset controlling my harddrives.

The weird thing is that some games work fine while other bsod a couple of minutes in. Battlefield 3 single player works fine but in MP mode I get a BSOD just minutes in to the level. I've checked the temperatures and the CPU hangs around at 75 degrees celsius under heavy load. The gpu stays at around 70 degrees celsius under heavy load. I played through Deus Ex: HR without any issues at all.

I have the OS on an OCZ Agility 3 SSD. I've updated its firmware since I saw some issues having to do with that. No avail. I've clocked down the graphics card and raised the max voltage to 1.038 since I saw some voltage related problems on the net aswell.

I'd like to be as certain as possible before I return the motherboard, any suggestions as to what I could do or have you had similar problems with similar specs?

ASUS P8Z68
Core I7 @ 3.3Ghz
ASUS GTX 570
OCZ Agility 3 SSD 120 GB

Comment: have you had any other problems with your HD? Also, what is the BSOD error code?

Comment: No other errors. I don't get a specific error code except for the hex codes at the bottom. It begins with 0x000000F4.

Comment: does it say "`STOP Error 0x000000F4`"? If not, could you provide the exact text of the BSOD?

Comment: You may also want to check some of the answers to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/342670/windows-7-64bit-stop-error-code-0x000000f4) similar question

Comment: Your CPU is running too hot.  Not hot enough to trigger this to happen, but hotter than the Intel Datasheet recommends (Intel says max. temp of 72C).  Just letting you know, you should get a heatsink or lower the voltage on it.  The GPU, however, is fine (and is rated to go up to 99C, although I would never go over 75).

Comment: Now, for your problem... Have you run [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)?  Let it run at least two complete tests and report back if your RAM is okay.

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver, yes, that's what it says. I read somewhere that this message could have to do with the HD.