# Windows BSOD Stop: 0x000000F4

Tags: windows, drivers, crash, bsod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 64bit STOP Error Code 0x000000F4](https://superuser.com/questions/342670/windows-7-64bit-stop-error-code-0x000000f4)

This is a brand new system, it was literally just built two days ago. I had installed it, moved my users directory to a second hard disc, and tried overclocking. It started crashing, I figured I messed up and so I reinstalled it. I used a program to move the users directory this time. More crashes, reinstalled and decided to do without. Now, it's still crashing, and I have no idea what's going on.

This is x64, retail, hardware is brand new, and it's been installed three times now. Each time I installed it, I installed all the drivers off the motherboard and graphics card cds.

The BSOD can happen any time from right after logging in, to a few hours after. The error message is always:

Stop: 0x000000F4 (0x0000000000000003, 0xFFFFFA8008778B30, 0XFFFFFA8008778E10, 0XFFFFF800831D2240)

What have I missed?

Note: the unknown device in perfmon is a wireless adapter, and the PCI device is likely a bluetooth interface. It still crashed anyway on another installation where they were installed, so i don't think it's them.

here's some dump/info files:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/b09x39 
http://www.mediafire.com/?7p2jjczj6r5pg3g

The links are just different sources for the same files.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost always hardware, occasionally it's drivers. I'd start with a four-hour run of [`memtest86+`](http://www.memtest.org).

Answer (score 0):

Check your memory cards to be all of the same kind and speed. Sometimes you need to verify the numbers on the chips.

Use your PC with as less devices as possible the first days.. Do not connect devices to your motherboard the first day. I mean with this: build a small computer, that's just capable of booting Windows.. Verify if it goes to a BSOD or not.

Check your BIOS settings for standard settings. Do not use overclocking before installing Windows.. Do not change power management settings after installing Windows.. The kernel is chosen based on your APM capabilities.

A processor heat up can crash Windows. Try downclocking the processor speed and memory speed and graphics card speed for testing purposes.

Start with only one video card, if you've got a SLI system, and so on...

The users directory may not be moved, the registry settings don't adapt to this immersive change.